# Get first N digits of a number

Tags: java, numbers

I'm writing a small program that displays the factorial of a number.
When I enter the number 20 I got the number 2432902008176640000 as result.

How can I limit a decimal number in Java.

For example the number 2432902008176640000 should be 2432 (limit 4).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use string.valueof and then substring

Comment: View this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895337/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-decimals-printed-for-a-double

Comment: @user..waht is the datatype?

Comment: [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class you can check...

Comment: facility number length is fixed or it may be change..?

Answer (score 9):

The following might do what you want, if what you want to do is what I think you want to do:

```
long n = 2432902008176640000L; // original number
while (n > 9999) {
   // while "more than 4 digits", "throw out last digit"
   n = n / 10;
}
// now, n = 2432
```

And [a demo](http://ideone.com/N431SU).

---

Notes:

1. A `long` can only represent values as large as 9223372036854775807 (which is only about 4 times as large as the number given) before it will overflow. If dealing with larger numbers you'll need to switch to [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or similar. The same technique can be used, updated for syntax differences.
2. As fge pointed out, this won't work as it is written over negative numbers; this can be addressed by either changing the condition (i.e. `n < -9999`) or first obtaining the absolute value of n (and then reverting the operation at the end).
3. As done in yinqiwen's answer, `n > 9999` can be replaced with `n >= (long)Math.pow(10, N)` (preferably using a temporary variable), where N represents the number of decimal digits.

Comment: Thank you user2864740! This is the solution of my problem :-)

Comment: Watch out that this will fail if the number is negative ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this, may help:

```
Long n = 2432902008176640000;
String num = String.valueOf(n);
num = num.subString(0, 4);
n = Long.valueOf(num);
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace N by the limit.

```
long v = 2432902008176640000L; 
long x = (long) Math.pow(10, N);

while(v >= x)
{
   v /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Fix for the edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the previous answers with loops are O(n) time complexity. Here's a solution for constant time complexity:

```
long num = 2432902008176640000L;
int n = 4;
long first_n = (long) (num / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(num)) - n + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you mean factorial of a number.
Just convert the number into a string and use substring method to get first 4 digits only.
fact is the factorial value

```
    String result_4_str=(fact+"").substring(0, 4);
    long result_4 = Long.parseLong(result_4_str);
    System.out.println(result_4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
long number = 2432902008176640000L ;
String numberStr = String.valueOf(number);      
if(numberStr.length()>=4){
    System.out.println(numberStr.substring(0, 4));      
}
```