# How to round float number in Android

Tags: java, android, double, decimal, rounding

I am stuck in the scenario below:

If x is 1.5 or lower then the final result will be x = 1.
If x is large than 1.5 then x = 2.

The input number will be x/100.

For instance:
input = 0.015 => x = 1.5 => display x = 1.

The problem I got is that float number is inaccurate. For example:
input = 0.015 but actually it is something like 0.01500000000000002. In this case, x gonna be 1.500000000000002 which is large than 1.5 => display output is x = 2.

It happen so randomly which I don't know how to solve it. Like 0.5, 1.5 will give me the correct result. But 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5 will give me the wrong result. Then 6.5 will give me the correct result again.

The code I implemented is below:

```
float x = 0.015;
NumberFormat nf = DecimalFormat.getPercentInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
output = nf.format(x);
```

So depends on x, the output might be right or wrong. It is just so random.

I alos tried to use Math.round, Math.floor, Math.ceils but none of them seems work since float number is so unpredictable.

Any suggestion for the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell me: **How much** is `0.01500000000000002` different from `0.01500000000000000`? isn't it **negligible**?

Comment: have you tried DecimalFormatter to limit numbers after decimal to a fix value ? ...see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895337/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-decimals-printed-for-a-double

Comment: That's how it is. Float and double values behave that way since not all decimal fractions can be represented exactly. If you need to represent decimal fractions exactly (e.g. for monetary values) you can use BigDecimal (but calculations are much slower).

Comment: same as you round in java

Comment: hum seems confused. So if I use BigDecimal, will I get the exact value? The  problem is that with the same input, iOS performs the correct results which Android only sometimes gives the correct results.

Comment: Can you add test case with expected output so that it is easier to check our answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my old code golf answer.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(math(1.5f));
        System.out.println(math(1.500001f));
        System.out.println(math(1.49999f));
    }

    public static int math(float f) {
        int c = (int) ((f) + 0.5f);
        float n = f + 0.5f;
        return (n - c) % 2 == 0 ? (int) f : c;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
1
2
1
```

Comment: Hi there, seems like the outputs I need. Can you explain a bit about the math function that you wrote please? I am not fully understand. Thanks.

Comment: Which part sir? Also I can explain it through skype :)

Comment: I am confused about using int c and float n?

Comment: the `int c` serves as the cutted value while the `float n` holds the full value of the result. Since your goal is to round when the number is greater than lets say 1.5, I am just going to check if there is a remainder. I'm really sorry I suck at explaining :(

Comment: the 1.5 will have no remainder but 1.5002 will have.

Comment: Yeah I tested all the possible situations. This is the correct answer. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121577/discussion-between-enzokie-and-long-dao).

Answer (score 6):

You could use `String.format`.

```
String s = String.format("%.2f", 1.2975118);
```

Answer (score 2):

I like simple answers,

```
Math.round(1.6); // Output:- 2
Math.round(1.5); // Output:- 2
Math.round(1.4); // Output:- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I used the `DecimalFormat`.  This might help you.

```
float x = 1.500000000000002f;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.######");
long l = df.format(x);
System.out.println("Value of l:"+l);
```

Comment: DecimalFormat returns String mate.

Comment: Yes, `DecimalFormat` is used to just specify the format that you want. And format() will take of it. Check with the output which is `long` not a `String`