# Format double value?

Tags: java

I have following line of code:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
System.out.println(df.format(23.00));
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(df.format(23.00d)));
System.out.println(df.parse("23.00").doubleValue());
```

First line print `23` but in 2nd and 3rd line when i convert it to double it prints `23.0` . showing `23.0` doesnt makes any sense.

How can i get a `double` value `23`.

I checked these [best-way-to-format-a-double-value-to-2-decimal-places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819842/best-way-to-format-a-double-value-to-2-decimal-places) [how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Comment: `23` and `23.0` are the same thing. If you want to print it without the `.0`, use a format string as in the first line.

Comment: `23` is not a `double`.  `23` is an integer.  `23.00` is a `double`.  If the first line prints the format you want, why parse the output into a double and display the double?  It's unclear what you are trying to solve because the answer is within your question.

Comment: In line two and three, you are casting it back to a double (was a String before), so Java will just print them as it always does.

Comment: You already have that value. In the last 2 lines you're not formatting the value as you'd like, you're just using `System.out.println(double x)` which by default outputs the value as described by the `Double.toString(double d)` implementation

Comment: What exactly do you want anyway? Print it as `23`, which you did in your first line, or print it as `23.00`?

Comment: showing `23.0` doesnt makes any sense.so I want it to be like `23`

Answer (score 3):

In the second and third output lines, you're just using `Double.toString` effectively. A `double` value doesn't remember whatever format it happens to have been parsed in to start with - it's just a numeric value.

If you want to format a value in a particular way, use `df.format` as you have in your first output line. For example:

```
String text = ...; // Wherever you get the text from
double value = Double.parseDouble(text);
String formatted = df.format(value); // Using the df you set up before
```

Comment: Are you saying that every time before showing i should format `23.0` so that it will be displayed as `23` ? can't i store it as `23`?

Comment: @Manish: Not unless you want to store it as an int, in which case you couldn't store 23.5 etc. Again: the format isn't part of the value.

Comment: yah correct but anyway it will store `23` as `23.0` in db. when i will read it back it will be `23.0` so formatting comes in the picture to make it `23`

Comment: @Manish: it doesn't store a textual representation at all. It stores a bunch of bits - the same bits for 23, 23.0, 23.00 etc. How your db stores it is a different matter.

Comment: take example of price i am storing it as double so when i store `120` and `150.5` and display back it shows as `120.0` `150.5` not `120` just cos java is treating `120` in double format.

Comment: @Manish: You should use `BigDecimal` instead of double for currency values to start with. But either way, you simply need to understand that when *displaying* a value, you should apply appropriate formatting to it.

Answer (score 0):

A `double` value, when converted to a `String`, will NEVER be an `integer`. It will always contains `decimals`.

If you want to print to the console a double as `23`, you can cast it to an `Int`:

```
System.out.println((int) yourDouble);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `double` if your number is `23`, it shown `23.0` because it is `double`.

If your meaning is to print an `int` value with 2-digits, you can use `System.out.printf("%.2d", number);`

I don't have any Java compiler on my system this time for test that, but I think it is true.