# Removing trailing 0 from return of a function

Tags: java

How can i remove the tailing zeros from the return of a function?
Here is the function, which is in another class.

```
static public double Area(double side1,double side2){
    return side1*side2;
}
```

and here is the calling function

```
System.out.println("Side 1 : ");
b1=new Scanner(System.in);
double side1=b1.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Side 2: ");
b2=new Scanner(System.in);
double side2=b2.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Area= "+Rectangle.Area(side1, side2));
```

For side1=10 and side2=10 the output will be

```
Area = 100.0
```

while i want it to be

```
Area = 100
```

and for example for values 0.25 and 2 will be

```
Area = 0.5
```

Comment: Do you understand that there's no difference in representation between 100 and 100.0? It's like asking a method to return an `int` in hex instead of in decimal... it's just a number. (The very concept of "a trailing zero" only applies to `double` when you format it as a string. That's not the case for something like `BigDecimal` though.)

Comment: Trailing zeros is an artifact of how you display a value, it's not something that is stored as part of the value.  Java != Cobol

Comment: If you want to drop those when outputting/converting to string: [*Format double value?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493051/java-format-double-value)

Comment: If you want to chop off any fractional portion, use a `long`: `return (long)(side1*side2);` (changing the method signature as well). Or if you want to round it, `Math.round()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to print a `double`, Java's `printf` and other similar features let you control issues including the number of digits, the use of the decimal separator, and the treatment of zero digits. More here: [How to display an output of float data with 2 decimal places in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-display-an-output-of-float-data-with-2-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DecimalFormat` to limit the decimals or drop trailing 0.

To limit decimals

```
double area = 0.1234;
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(numberFormat.format(area));
```

It will give output as `0.12`

You can use number of 0's as per requirement.

OR

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", area);
```

If you want to drop trailing `0` use `#.#` so `0.50` will be `0.5`

```
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
```