# Return double with two decimal from long

Tags: java, casting, double, decimal, long-integer

I want to set a long number to a double number.
The problem is I want to return it as decimal format.
For ex: I have a long number

```
long a = 123456;
```

then I cast `double b = (double) a;`
Now b show `1.234**E**5`.
I want b show exactly like `a: 123456.0`. Don't want "**E**" here
I cast it to String and then agian parse to double. Like this

```
b = Double.parseDouble(new Long(a).toString()));
```

Anyone have better idea pls share it to me.
Thank you.

Comment: Casting is irrelevant. You want *formatting*, as in *string formatting*.

Comment: use DecimalFormat,http://stackoverflow.com/a/8819889/3651739

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819842/best-way-to-format-a-double-value-to-2-decimal-places?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806278/double-decimal-formatting-in-java?rq=1 for ideas

Answer (score 1):

No need to cast to long or use toString on Double object.

Just use DescimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
System.out.println(f.format(123456L));
```

As you can see 123456L is a long numeric value, but it is formatted as you wanted.

Good Luck.

Comment: It will be formated.
But what I want is a double number to return without "E".
I used String as a temp. Then parse to double.
b = Double.parseDouble(new Long(a).toString()))
Your way is use DecimalFormat as a temp, then parse to double.
Which way is better

Comment: @AnTran: So your question is quite different, because anybody would take your question as formatting the output while printing double values. If your question is about converting the long to double the way is double d = new Double(123456L); If you see the double as ###E## this is the way it is being printed with the default format. But it is a double value. E representation is the format of printing not the value itself.