# I need to be able to capture decimals with only 2 digits after the decimal point java, tried this

Tags: java, floating-point, int, double, decimal

I need to be able to capture decimals with only 2 digits after the decimal

point java, tried this

This is my code , i need to know be able to read with 2 decimal places

```
package project.pkg1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * @author Maria Andrea Quintana 4891405 *
 * @author Salvador Frias
 */
public class Project1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        String s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the purchase amount");


        if (s1 == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a valid integer");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (s1.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a valid integer");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i = i + 1) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(s1.charAt(i))) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter an integer value");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you want 2 digits after decimal point eg if input is 455.1689 it should take 455.16 right?

Comment: yes, basically i want one decimal point and 2 places

Comment: When working with monetary values, also have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285680/representing-monetary-values-in-java

Comment: @mariaandreaerramouspe Don't replace the question like that. Simply accept the answer you like by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. *Question restored.*

Comment: i m new to this and did n t know it will be an issue, sorry

Comment: Why aswers has TOTALLY nothign to code presented in question?

Comment: @JacekCz Because OP keeps *changing* the question. **Maria:** Stop that. Ask a *new* question, don't change this one. *Question restored (again)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a DecimalFormat to format your double:

```
    double input = 455.1689;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    System.out.println(df.format(input));
```

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819842/best-way-to-format-a-double-value-to-2-decimal-places) dealing with the same problem.

**EDIT 2:**
Delete the for loop and put this code in its place

```
    double input = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    s1 = df.format(input);
```

Comment: i don t get it, i want to modify what i have, so should i write another if for that one?

Comment: Could you tell us what s1 is? A TextField? A String?

Comment: a string sorry... s1 is the amount of the sale

Comment: should i name input amountGiven, or the name i gave it for the other calculations/.?

Comment: Could you edit your question and post all of your code? That would help us see what you are trying to do.

Comment: can i modify this ===> for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i = i + 1) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(s1.charAt(i))) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter an integer value");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

Comment: i did, take a look now

Comment: If you input something like 23, should it accept it? Or should it always have a decimal

Comment: it work perfect with everything but, even after i receive change, but when i input let s say 2.50 it does not take it

Comment: where should i place it, before or afte the if statements?

Comment: After the if statements, where the for loop is right now

Comment: oh, youmean replace the for loop ?

Comment: String s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the purchase amount");
          if (s1 == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a valid integer");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (s1.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a valid integer");
            System.exit(0);
        }
         double input = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    s1 = df.format(input);
     
        }
                  
        double purchaseAmount = Double.parseDouble(s1);

Comment: you are awesome Oliver

Comment: thank you soooooooo much, i have been working on this for the past 24 to 36 hs lol

Comment: No problem, if the answer is right, click the green arrow on my answer to accept it

Comment: now if i put letter it doesn  t work, is there any way to take what the loop did for letters and symbols

Comment: Ohhhhh ok i see what u did.... Omg oliver, i have learned more today than in 3 weeks of class.... cannot thank you enoughhhhhhh

Comment: idk how now it doesn t take decimals, is that even possible. after it was working before?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

`s1` is your text or string value:

```
   String s=String.format("output: %.2f", s1);
                System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: i just don t know how to do it in terms of s1.

Comment: i want to modify this, for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i = i + 1) {
    if (!Character.isDigit(s1.charAt(i))) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter an integer value");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

Comment: so what you are telling is from string you want only two digit after a decimal is that correct?

Comment: i posted my whole code, edited my question, take a look and tell me if you see what should i modify please

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with money which can be of different *[currency unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency#Modern_currencies)*'s. I would suggest you to take a look at *[Moneta API](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javamoney/moneta)*

### Maven dependency to add:

```
<!-- Moneta -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
      <artifactId>moneta</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

### Example:

```
MonetaryAmount monetaryAmount = MonetaryAmounts.getDefaultAmountFactory()
.setNumber(3.45)
.setCurrency("USD")
.create();

System.out.println("EXACT MONETARY VALUE: "+monetaryAmount.getNumber().doubleValueExact()); // 3.45
System.out.println("VALUE AFTER DECIMAL: "+monetaryAmount.getNumber().getAmountFractionNumerator()); // 45
```

### Edit:

If you are allowed to use *[regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html)*, I think this is what you are looking for

```
String s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the purchase amount");
double d = 0.0;

int counter = 0;
Matcher match = Pattern.compile("[aA-zZ]+").matcher(s1);
while (match.find()) {
    counter++;
}

if((!s1.isEmpty()) && (s1.trim().length()!=0) && (counter == 0)){
    if(s1.contains(".")){
        String[] strings = s1.split("\\.");
        if (strings[1].length() > 2) {
            System.out.println("Maximum 2 places allowed after decimal.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    d = Double.parseDouble(s1);
}else if(counter > 0){
    System.out.println("Only numeric values are allowed");
    System.exit(0);
}
System.out.println("Expected input retrieved: " + d);
```

Comment: problem is...we have not seen that yet. and i cannot use stuff we have not seen in class. this is the 3rd week so stuff is pretty basic.

Comment: Yes, something like that, thank you so much for taking the time to help

Comment: That's ok. You could even refactor validations into individual methods and test them indvidually. Take a look at this [refactored code](https://pastebin.com/g1RQJ82z) and try running it, validate for different test cases and enhance accordingly. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

```
      String s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the purchase amount");

    if (s1 == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a valid integer");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if (s1.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a valid integer");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if (s1.equals("0")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a valid integer");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if (s1.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a valid integer");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    double input = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    s1 = df.format(input);
```