# java - round currency to 2 decimal places

Tags: java, decimal, currency, decimalformat

I have a small problem which i can't seem to solve.

I want to print out my Balance in a '£100.50' format but it's currently giving me a '£100.5' format.

I'm using a decimalFormat method but it's not working. Any help why?

```
final DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

balance = 100.499999;
System.out.println("Balance: £ " + df2.format(balance));
```

**Fixed the error by changing ("#.##") to ("#.00")**

Comment: See this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819842/best-way-to-format-a-double-value-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: @TomasBisciak Nope doesn't work gives me an error

Comment: @imraanstack1 Did any of these worked for you ? Please accept answer if it works for you, also there are some quesitons you had and didnt marked as answered , check them out in your profile to give people reward for theyr help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
balance = 100.499999;
System.out.println("Balance: £ " + df2.format(balance));
```

This should work

From @A2H's answer I would like to make a note.

Suppose, you have

```
balance = .7538;
```

If you want it to be 0.75 then use

```
new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

or if you want to be .75 then use

```
new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Comment: Hmm good point, I was just testing my code and when there is 50p in the balance it only shows .50. How would i do it to show 0.50?

Comment: use newDecimalFormat("0.00");

Comment: Doesn't work. Still gives me the error .50 and not 0.50

Answer (score 2):

This works: `new DecimalFormat("0.00");`

**UPDATE**

For a complete understanding of the patterns used in `java.text.DecimalFormat` refer to Java API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
double value= 213.3456;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");      
System.out.println(df.format(value));
```