# How to create a double with two decimals in Android Studio

Tags: numbers, format, decimal

if users input "5" at "akenari" textview and click "altmis" button "bkenari" print 1.66666666√3 but I want print 1.66√3 how can I do?

```
altmis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                double sayi1f=Double.parseDouble(akenari.getText().toString());
                bkenari.setText(String.valueOf(sayi1f / 3 + "√3"));
            }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to Format a Double value to 2 Decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819842/best-way-to-format-a-double-value-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: use  `Math.round()` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let your value to be roundoff is `x`

```
double x = 1.66666;
double y = Math.round(x*100.0)/100.0;
```

then `y` will easily give you the answer

no big logic used here

Comment: i need 1.66√3 , not integer . user input 5 , 8, 11 etc this print x,xxxxxxx√3 but i want only x,xx√3

Comment: `double num = Math.round((sayi1f / 3)*100.0)/100.0;`    
`bkenari.setText(String.valueOf( num+ "√3"));`    
just copy & see it will give 1.66√3