# Conversion of a floating value without E- notation

Tags: java, android, numbers

I have different float values like

- 0.0000009
- 8145.32
- 123.00001
- 1235.01000

I want them showing to a `TextView` or converting them to string without getting an exponential notation.
when I use `String.format("%.8f", num)`, It is getting random values after the real number ( num =  8145.32 -> 8145.32539487).

Help me, Thank you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: If you want 2 decimal places, use a DecimalFormat like so: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); ` careful though, it might not round the way you want

Comment: `System.out.println(String.format("%.8f", 8145.32));` -> `8145.32000000`

Comment: Try `new DecimalFormat("#.############").format(value)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this use [**`DecimalFormat`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

> `DecimalFormat` is a concrete subclass of `NumberFormat` that formats decimal numbers. It has a variety of features designed to make it possible to parse and format numbers in any locale, including support for Western, Arabic, and Indic digits

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
 Double value = 123456434.678;
 DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
 Log.e("MY_VALUES", decimalFormat.format(value));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
com.example.nilesh.testapp E/MY_VALUES: 123456434.68
```

Comment: This seems a good answer to me. I see no actual reason to downvote it.

Comment: I am not sure it gives anything better than the OP's `String.format("%.8f", num)`

Comment: @NileshRathod Can't get the reason for that.

Comment: @KlingKlang sir agree with u

Comment: `String.format()` can produce ***weird results*** in its precision, while `DecimalFormat()` is ***exact***. See this: http://javadevnotes.com/java-float-to-string-without-exponential-scientific-notation

Comment: If this is actually the answer, isn't it a duplicate of something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819842/best-way-to-format-a-double-value-to-2-decimal-places ? Just asking...

Comment: @HBo Not an exact duplicate, but very close to that. Good find.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what I need is not in that link.

Comment: Guys I need full decimal part except last zeros

Comment: @AfinasEM  try this **`DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");`**

Comment: @ Nilesh Rathod, The problem is I need the whole decimal part (except zeros).The number may contain 10 digits on the decimal part.