# Format double array values to one decimal place

Tags: java, arrays, formatting

I cant find an effective way to format the inside of the array  to one decimal place.

Then there is a issue with the stopwatch I have towards the end of the code to keep track of how long it takes for the bubble sort to process based on the array size.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class BubbleSortTest {
    public static void sort(double arr[]) {
        int arrayLength = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayLength-i-1; j++) {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
                    //swap temp and arr[i]
                    double temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

/* Prints the array */
public static void printArray(double arr[]) {
    int arrayLength = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void generateDoubleArray(double arr[], int length) {
    //generating random values
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr[i] = (rand.nextDouble() * (100 - 0)) + 0;
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    BubbleSortTest ob = new BubbleSortTest();
    int length = 3; //change the length according to requirement
    double arr[] = new double[length]; // Ex) {6.1, 4.2, 3.3, 7.4, 5.5, 2.6, 8.7, 1.8};
    BubbleSortTest.generateDoubleArray(arr, length);
    System.out.println("BEFORE BUBBLE SORT: "+ Arrays.toString(arr));
    BubbleSortTest.sort(arr);
    System.out.println("AFTER BUBBLE SORT: "+ Arrays.toString(arr));

    StopWatch s = new StopWatch();
    double[] a;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        a = BubbleSortTest.generateDoubleArray(i * 20000, i*30000);
        s.start();
        sort(a);
        s.stop();
        System.out.println("Size: " + i*1000 + "\t\tTime: " +s.elapsedTime());
    }
}
   // Size: 1000        Time: 0.0
   // Size: 2000        Time: 0.0
   // Size: 3000        Time: 0.0
   // Size: 4000        Time: 0.0
   // Size: 5000        Time: 0.0
   // Size: 6000        Time: 0.0
   // Size: 7000        Time: 0.0
   // Size: 8000        Time: 0.0
   // Size: 9000        Time: 0.0
   // Size: 10000       Time: 0.0

 // Output with length of array = 3 
 // BEFORE BUBBLE SORT: [56.24793454034215, 1.3614871074902335,17.853054450932547]
  //AFTER BUBBLE SORT: [1.3614871074902335,17.853054450932547,56.24793454034215]
```

Comment: There is `String.format()` which allows to adjust the formatting in the desired way.

Comment: What is the error (edit the question to show it as properly formatted text)?

Comment: Where would I be adding that?

Comment: Either append it to the question (with some explanation) or, if it is a different problem, create a new question.

Comment: I just finished editing it all, sorry about that!

Comment: In `a = BubbleSortTest.generateDoubleArray(i * 20000, i*30000);` the first parameter of `generateDoubleArray()` should be the array to fill with random doubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you're not calling your printArray method...

There isn't a way to format doubles within a number array. You'll have to create a new String array with the formatted values, then print that, if you want to use `Arrays.toString`

If you use your own method, you can see several solutions at [Best way to Format a Double value to 2 Decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819842/best-way-to-format-a-double-value-to-2-decimal-places)

Regarding the error, it's not clear what you're expecting `generateDoubleArray(i * 20000, i*30000);` to do, but the first parameter is required to be a double array, not a number, plus the method itself returns nothing, so you won't be able to do `a = BubbleSortTest.generateDoubleArray`

Perhaps you wanted something like so

```
static Random rand = new Random();

public static double[] generateDoubleArray(int length){
    double arr[] = new double[length];
    for(int i = 0; i<length;i++) {
        //generating random values
        arr[i] = rand.nextDouble() * 100;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Besides that, `("Size: " + i*1000 +` in the output is way far off from the length parameter that you're trying to create

Comment: I see, I am gonna have to work on that. What about the situation with the stopwatch?

Comment: Well, the code given doesn't compile, so I'm not sure how you're getting that output

Comment: You might also want to reset or recreate a new stopwatch within the loop. Otherwise, you are repeatedly stopping and starting the same one, and I'm not sure it ever goes back to zero