# calculating numbers after . (dot) in java

Tags: java, calculation

I am new to Java. creating calculator which calculates number from user input.
I have 2 Jtextfield in my application where user input numbers.
For example in first field user input 45678.230 and in second field 23214.210 which gives me subtraction result is 22464 but everything i want is full result followed by .(dot) so my answer should be 22464.02

```
String n1opn = n1open.getText();
String n1clsd = n1close.getText();
        
        
double n1intopen = (int) Double.parseDouble(n1opn);
double n1intclose = (int) Double.parseDouble(n1clsd);
double n1ltr = n1intclose - n1intopen;

System.out.println("output  "+ n1ltr);
```

Comment: Why cast to `int` if you need a double?

Comment: Did you check here? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819842/best-way-to-format-a-double-value-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: @Nikhil_10 the question is phrased in a confusing way, but they're basically asking why there's no decimal part in the result, and that's because they're truncating their inputs by casting them to `int`.

Comment: thanks @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: OP, please brush up on the basic data types that java provides

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You seem to be casting your inputs to an `int`. Integers don't have any decimal bits so using `double` is correct for your case!