# extracting a double value from a string of alphanumeric characters in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a function that does what the heading says.

I ended up with writing code that parses through every character and making another string then **Double.parseDouble**. Which threw `StringIndexoutOfBounds` exception. Which is clearly not the way to go.

> The block of code is here

```
int i = 0;
char c = q.charAt(i);
if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
    try {
        String h = "" + c;
        while (Character.isDigit(c) || c == '.') {
            if (i == (q.length() - 1)) if (Character.isDigit(q.charAt(i + 1)) || (q.charAt(i + 1) == '.')) {
                Log.i("CalcApps", "within while");
                h += q.charAt(i + 1);
            }
            i++;
            c = q.charAt(i);
        }
        result = Double.parseDouble(h);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("MyApps", "Index is out of bounds");
    }
}
```

Comment: What format does your `String` have? Maybe you just need to `trim()` or clean it up before the call to `Double.parseDouble()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and avoid creating your own implementation of a parser. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054132/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-of-decimalformat-from-comma-to-dot-point) for some examples.

Comment: I'm not trying to format a decimal. I'm trying to pasrse a double value : ex: q = 123.1445+e^x(23.2) Ans: 123.1445, 23.2

Comment: You can do that with the `Number DecimalFormat.parse(String string, ParsePosition position)` method

Answer (score 3):

You would try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "dsde1121zszs.15szs"; 
        Double d = Double.valueOf(str.replaceAll("[^0-9\\.]", ""));
        System.out.println(d);
    }
```