# DecimalFormat thousandths separator

Tags: java

I'm trying to set an apostrophe separator for the decimal format for a fractional number with a millionth place.  I am getting a malformed pattern error.

```
String text = ".000'000";
DecimalFormat dformat = new DecimalFormat(text);
```

What is the correct string to use?

Comment: Check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5054217/2024761).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html, you need two single quotes, one after the other.  The first will be seen as an escape character.