# DecimalFormat "Multiple decimal separators in pattern"

Tags: java, formatting, supercsv

I want to format decimal values as a currency value: 1234.56d should become "1.234,56" (this format is used in some European countries).
I'm using the following pattern to format decimal values:

```
final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.###.###,00");
final String formatted = df.format(1234.56d);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

In fact I'm using [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net)'s class [FmtNumber](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/cellprocessor/FmtNumber.html#FmtNumber%28java.lang.String%29), but that doesn't matter, because the pattern syntax is the same: new FmtNumber("###.###.###,00");

What I get is an IllegalArgumentException with the message "Multiple decimal separators in pattern".

I understand that there can be only one decimal separator. But in my case it should be the sign ",". And "," appears only one time in my pattern.

I searched the Web and StackOverflow for this exception message, but I found no helpful answers.

What's my error?

Comment: Look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054132/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-of-decimalformat-from-comma-to-dot-point

Comment: You are right, that one is helpful. I haven't found it by searching. But my misunderstanding was that I meant "," literally, but it's only a symbol for the Grouping separator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) in a format string `.` is **always** the decimal separator and `,` is **always** a grouping separator.

Its actual representation in the formatted `String` is given by the locale of the formatter instance.

For example

```
final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.00", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

If you look at the [javadoc](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/cellprocessor/FmtNumber.html#FmtNumber%28java.lang.String%29) for `FmtNumber` is clearly says "using the DecimalFormat class and the default locale" - so you need to have the correct default `Locale` for this to work.

Comment: Great! new FmtNumber("###,###,##0.00") is working as expected. So "." and "," are only symbols. I see.

Comment: FmtNumber("###,###,##0.00") is better than FmtNumber("###,###,###.00") because the latter formats 0d as ",00".

Answer (score 0):

You should to format with culture, not custom strings. Just use:

```
decimalNumber.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"));
```