# Big Decimal Round to two decimals ALWAYS (even if my BigDecimal object has no decimals)?

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

**How can I round BigDecimal objects to 2 decimals always (even if my BigDecimal object has no decimals)?**

I'm doing:

```
myBigDecimal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); // works fine when it has decimals
```

Context: I have a List of POJO's that when I send to the front end I give them format in ExtJs

**BUT**

I am generating a CSV file also and I've been required that all of the economic fields have 2 decimals.

Any ideas or work arounds?

Thx

Comment: So in other words, you are just saying if your BigDecimal is say 10, you want 10.00 and it's not producing the decimals? Really??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`java.text.DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class to format decimal numbers. e.g.

**Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.00", symbols);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(12.456)));
    System.out.println(formatter.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(12L)));
}
```

**Output**:

```
12.46
12.00
```

See more in [*Customizing Formats (The Java Tutorials > Internationalization > Formatting)*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

Comment: Ok, but I'm getting 12,00 instead of 12.00, do you know why? and I'm not configuring any specific locale.

Comment: Yes it's for your locale.. @Ingo i have the same strange locale ..check this quiestion for [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054132/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-of-decimalformat-from-comma-to-dot-point)

Answer (score 2):

> I am generating a CSV file

This means that you are *not* dealing with *rounding* - rather, you are dealing with *formatting*. In other words, it does not matter how many digits are there after the decimal point in the actual number: all you want is to put the proper number of digits in the text file that you are generating.

> I've been required that all of the economic fields have 2 decimals.

One way of doing it is using `printf`'s formatting capabilities:

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(12.5);
System.out.printf("%.2f", bd);
```

[demo.](http://ideone.com/VYyULC)