# DecimalFormat("#0.000") doesn't format the right way like 1.321 instead of this it delievers 1,321

Tags: android, numberformatexception, decimalformat

I want to get a `Double` with 3 decimalplaces. **I do this:**

```
String sAveragePrice;

Double dAveragePrice = holePrice/(allPrices.size());    // delivers 1.3210004       
DecimalFormat threeZeroes = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
sAveragePrice = threeZeroes.format(dAveragePrice);          // delivers then 1,321
```

After formatting I dont get a 1.321 but 1,321. And the 1,321 throws a `NumberformatException` later. **This is when it is thrown:**

```
Double priceInt = Double.parseDouble(sAveragePrice);  // throws NumberFormatException
```

The strange thing is, I have this code till 3 weeks and it didn't make any problem. But today when I have started my app again it gets problem with it. But I didn't have changed anything.

Can anybody help me? **I also tried this:**

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
sAveragePrice = format.format(dAveragePrice);
```

But it also delivers me a "," instead of a "." for double.

Comment: String sAveragePrice;

Comment: see me answer to know wot I mean

Answer (score 0):

Try using a locale for you number format.

```
Number format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ITALIAN);
```

Java SDK has a limited number of predefined locale settings, so for other locales (e.g., for Russian), you can use the following snippet:

```
Number format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("ru", "RU"));
Number format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("it", "IT")); // etc...
```

Comment: no it doesnt change anything. I think the code is right but anything else go wrong. Because my code works yesterday and today it's doing s**t things but I didn't change it.

Comment: @aut_silvia, make sure you didn't change your system settings

Answer (score 0):

this sample code may help you...

```
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    // set Locale.US as default
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.000");
    double d = 14.5589634d;
    String format = decimalFormat.format(d);
    System.out.println(format);// prints 14.559
    // back to default locale
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

Comment: no it doesnt change anything. I think the code is right but anything else go wrong. Because my code works yesterday and today it's doing s**t things but I didn't change it

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this SO question

[How to change the decimal separator of DecimalFormat from comma to dot/point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054132/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-of-decimalformat-from-comma-to-dot-point)

Basically your output will be Locale specific, so if you have a Locale of Frame then it will be different to a Locale of the US.

try

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
```

Comment: no it doesnt change anything. I think the code is right but anything else go wrong. Because my code works yesterday and today it's doing s**t things but I didn't change it

Answer (score 0):

Use this type of formatting
use # instead of 0. It is the correct format to declare your pattern

```
String sAveragePrice;

Double dAveragePrice = holePrice/(allPrices.size());       
DecimalFormat threeZeroes = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
sAveragePrice = threeZeroes.format(dAveragePrice);
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: no it doesnt change anything. I think the code is right but anything else go wrong. Because my code works yesterday and today it's doing s**t things but I didn't change it

Comment: then you must clean your project remove all dependency from properties-->java build path-->library clean it again and build . Restart you system and eclipse. It should work because it is working my side.