# Scala: Print Double with decimal and thousands seperator and 2 decimal places

Tags: scala, formatting

I am trying to print a double like this:

```
val Double = 12591294124.125124
printf("%,2f", Double)
```

with the wanted output: `12.591.294.124,13`

Oddly enough, when using "%,2f" it doesn't round to 2 decimal places, but prints 6 like this: `12.591.294.124,125124`
Is there a way to use the `,` as decimal seperator and round to 2 digits?
thanks!

Comment: `printf("%,.2f", Double)`, but the grouping and decimal symbol are locale dependent, if this is not what you want, you can look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054132/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-of-decimalformat-from-comma-to-dot-point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may choose Belgium locale to get this representation:

```
import java.util.Locale._

val belgiumLocale = getAvailableLocales.filter(_.getDisplayCountry == "Belgium")
                                       .head

val Double = 12591294124.125124
"%,.2f".formatLocal(belgiumLocale, Double)
// 12.591.294.124,13
```

Answer (score 1):

```
println(f"$Double%,.2f") // -> 12,591,294,124.13
println(f"$Double%,.2f"
  .replace(',', '-')
  .replace('.', ',')
  .replace('-', '.')) // -> 12.591.294.124,13
```

Comment: really, this proposed solution is ugly.