# Show decimal of a double only when needed (rounding issue)

Tags: java

I am trying to get a desired output based on a variable input. I can get close to what I want but there seems to be an issue with rounding a number.

What I want by example (input > output).

```
30 > 30
30.0 > 30
30.5 > 30,5
30.5555 > 30,6
30.04 > 30
```

The problem is that the last one comes back as 30.0. Now I understand why this is happening (because of the rounding up/down)

My code:

```
private String getDistanceString(double distance) {
        distance = 30.55;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".#");
        if (distance == Math.floor(distance)) {
            //If value after the decimal point is 0 change the formatting
            df = new DecimalFormat("#");
        }
        return (df.format(distance) + " km").replace(".", ",");
    }
```

Comment: you don't need to replace to get a comma as decimal separator http://stackoverflow.com/q/5054132/995714

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc thank you for that addition. That indeed looks nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost always wrong to use `==` with floating point numbers. You should use `Math.abs(a - b) < x`.

```
private String getDistanceString(double distance) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".#");
    if (Math.abs(distance - Math.round(distance)) < 0.1d) {
        //If value after the decimal point is 0 change the formatting
        df = new DecimalFormat("#");
    }
    return (df.format(distance) + " km").replace(".", ",");
}

public void test() {
    double[] test = {30d, 30.0d, 30.5d, 30.5555d, 30.04d, 1d / 3d};
    for (double d : test) {
        System.out.println("getDistanceString(" + d + ") = " + getDistanceString(d));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed my problem, and indeed shame on me for using ==

Comment: actually it's not a good way for float equal comparison. [Most effective way for float and double comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17333/995714), [The Floating-Point Guide comparison](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/)

Comment: I just noticed that while it works with the examples I gave in my question it doesn't do what I want if the input is for example 30.99 which makes the output 31,0. Which should be 31. I tried adjusting the code a bit but came to the conclusion I do not understand it enough to do so. Could you help me further?

Comment: @RekijanKileren - Try using `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor`.

Answer (score 0):

A hack around it, is to replace with regex

```
return 
       (""+df.format(distance))
       .replaceAll("\\.(0+$)?", ",") //replace . and trailing 0 with comma,
       .replaceAll(",$","") //if comma is last char, delete it
       + " km"; //and km to the string
```