# Format String in java

Tags: java, number-formatting

How do I format a string with commas to display in curreny format?

Assume the incoming string is a big number. For example:

> "1234567901234567890123456"

I want result as:

> "12,345,678,901,234,567,890,123,456"

The `DecimalFormat` in Java has a limitation to format a big number.

Comment: I think you should not be asking these kind of direct questions, it is easy search - https://www.google.co.in/search?q=format+currency+in+java&oq=format+currency+in+java .. Better try something and show where you are getting problem.

Comment: Why don't you google around?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7):

95% of problems are solved by clarifying your requirements. Let's filter out the things that are definitely not requirements. "incoming string is a big number" - that statement can never hold true. Is it a String? If yes, then it's a String, and never a number. This distinction is important. I'll assume that the answer to this question is "yes".

Now that you have a String, why are you using a DecimalFormat? What does a String have to do with a decimal number formatter? Nothing related to the problem that you are trying to solve. I'll leave the determination of the correct approach to solve your problem up to you - after all, my speculations at your requirements may not be correct.

To reiterate, here are the things that are definitely incorrect:
- You have a String, that is a big number"
- DecimalFormat has an issue with "big numbers" - an unsubstantiated conclusion drawn on a false basis of understanding.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(35634646));
```

**Output**: `35,634,646`

Comment: this not work with the OP number `System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format("1234567901234567890123456"));`

Comment: @hamzox Answer can be "accepted" only when question is at least 15 minutes old. Also in current form you are not handling big numbers as OP shows in question. You can use BigInteger here.

Comment: Wait, I am modifying my answer.

Comment: In other words you can replace `.format(35634646)` with `.format(new BigInteger("12345678901234567890123456")`.

Answer (score 2):

This would do

```
double formatThis = Double.parseDouble(yourNumber);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(formatThis));
```

Comment: this print `1 234 567 901 234 567 800 000 000,00` ??

Comment: @YCF_L, this will print  `1,234,567,901,234,567,800,000,000.00 ` , any doubt?

Comment: no, idea, i don't know in my system it print this `1 234 567 901 234 567 800 000 000,00`

Comment: i also have no idea, why your system prints that way , could be good question , post it , happy to see.

Comment: you need maybe to define the Local for that i get this instead your input take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054132/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-of-decimalformat-from-comma-to-dot-point

Comment: It is locale dependent. Use locale which have commas instead of spaces, like `Locale.US`. But `Double.parseDouble(yourNumber);` doesn't solve OP problem since `Double.parseDouble("1234567901234567890123456");` requires more precision than double can give and it parses it to `1 234 567 901 234 567 800 000 000,00` which is *not* what OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve the desired using the expression posted below:

```
(?n:(^\$?(?!0,?\d)\d{1,3}(?=(?<1>,)|(?<1>))(\k<1>\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?)$)
```

Comment: Can you include some usage example of this expression?

Comment: Can someone explain to me why a regex solves a string formatting thing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String input = "12345678901234567890123456";
String output = String.format("%,d", new BigInteger(input));
System.out.println(output);
// -> 12,345,678,901,234,567,890,123,456
```

Comment: Use `String.format(Locale.US, "%,d", new BigInteger(input));` to have commas instead of spaces.

Comment: @Pshemo, this throws an exception : `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "012‌​3456"`

Comment: @davidxxx You have some unprintable characters in your string between 2 and 3. Take a look at result of `Arrays.toString("012‌​3456".chars().toArray())`. It is [48, 49, 50, 8204, 8203, 51, 52, 53, 54] so you have there `8204` which is [Zero Width Non-Joiner](https://unicode-table.com/en/200C/) and `8203` which is [Zero Width Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/200B/).

Comment: @Pshemo You are totally right. Thank a lot for this explanation. I remark also it when I double click on the text, it select only the first part  as if the String was split into 2. I had never encountered this behavior on my IDE.