# Make java write floats with dot instead of comma

Tags: java

I'm from Sweden, and Eclipse and/or my Java installation seems to know this, because it prints floats with a comma instead of a dot, so `0.01` is written as `0,01`, which is the standard here. I want to write some floats to file and then read and plot them with python, so I'm afraid that the commas are going to give me trouble. How can I make Java write to file with the dot instead of comma?

For example:

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try{    
    bw = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(filename) );
    bw.write(String.format("%d;%f", 1, 0.000268));
    bw.newLine();
    bw.flush();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

should produce:

```
1;0.000268
```

instead of

```
1;0,000268
```

.

Comment: It's locale-specific. If you don't want that, use properly configured `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: `NumberFormat`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5054217/6099347

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...- Pass the locale to use when formatting numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the decimal separator of DecimalFormat from comma to dot/point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054132/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-of-decimalformat-from-comma-to-dot-point)

Comment: Make python locale sensitive. You can't?

Answer (score 2):

As JB Nizet pointed out, you can specify a Locale:

```
String.format(Locale.US, "%d;%f", 1, 0.000268)
```