# 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double' for European languages, using Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

each solution I've found for this uses java rather than Kotlin, please can anyone help?
I've written an app and I'm just trying to translate to some European countries, however the math part is falling over as Germans, French etc use commas rather than a full stop. I can't figure out how to fix this with the solutions on here.

part of .kt file:

```
import java.math.RoundingMode
import java.text.DecimalFormat
...
val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
val lengthCalc = 0.01658
val length = df.format(lengthCalc)
```

any help appreciated thanks

EDIT: I have looked here: [How to change the decimal separator of DecimalFormat from comma to dot/point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054132/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-of-decimalformat-from-comma-to-dot-point) but as I said originally, all the solutions are for Java, not Kotlin

Comment: The fact your using Kotlin makes no real difference here: you are using the Java API, so the answers in the duplicate apply, because they are more about API usage than about language (Java vs Kotlin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't try it at the moment but something like

```
val otherSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols()
otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',')
otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.')
DecimalFormat df = DecimalFormat("#.##", otherSymbols)
df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
val lengthCalc = 0.01658
val length = df.format(lengthCalc)
```

should do the trick. You need to use decimal format symbols for Europe, so a comma for the decimals and a full stop for the thousands.

An alternative to do it on a locale basis is to use NumberFormat and cast it to a DecimalFormat

```
val df = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(currentLocale) as DecimalFormat
df.applyPattern("#.##")
...
df.format(lengthCalc)
```

Comment: Does `DecimalFormatSymbols()` use the current locale by default?

Comment: Thanks William, however Code-Apprentice is correct, it needs to work everywhere

Comment: @Maff My original comment might be incorrect, so I deleted it. See my new comment. I suggest researching how `DecimalFormatSymbols` works.

Comment: thank you v much William, marked as answer, much appreciated

Comment: @Maff I've updated the answer to something simpler which should work on a per-locale (everywhere) basis provided that a locale can be determined (currentLocale)