# Exception while trying to convert String value to Double in Java

Tags: java, types

I am getting the below error when trying to convert  string to double.

```
For input string: "1,514,230.15"

Exception:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,514,230.15"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
```

This is the line of code I am using

```
 testString = "1,514,230.15"
 double d= Double.parseDouble(TestString);
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't have commas if you're directly doing `Double.parseDouble`, since you don't put commas in doubles in Java source code either

Comment: Possibly related: [How to change the decimal separator of DecimalFormat from comma to dot/point?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5054132) (then you can use those formats like `df.parse(stringRepresentingFormattedDouble).doubleValue()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```
String testString = "1,514,230.15".replace(",", "");
double d = Double.parseDouble(testString);
System.out.println(d);
```

**Or Solution 2:**

```
String input = "1,514,230.15";
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
double result = numberFormat.parse(input).doubleValue();
System.out.println(result);
```

**Or Solution 3:**

```
String testString = "1514230.15";
double d= Double.parseDouble(testString);
System.out.println(d);
```

**Output:**

```
1514230.15
```

**Explanation:**

1. In `solution 1` used `replace` method to replace all `,` i.e. `replace(",", "");`
2. In `solution 2` used [NumberFormat](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numberformat-class-java/). This class provides the interface for formatting and parsing numbers.
3. In `solution 3` removed all `,` from `testString` i.e. `String testString = "1514230.15";`

Comment: It is worth explaining *why* NumberFormat.parse is different from Double.parseDouble:  NumberFormat is intended for *human readable* numbers as they would be presented to end users, like the string in the original question;  Double.parseDouble is intended for *code formatted* numbers, that is, numeric values as they would appear in Java code.

Comment: Moreover, you stealthily copied [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62351764/10819573) and put that as one of your options. Whenever you copy someone's solution, do it with citation.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [NumberFormat#prase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) which is specialized for such conversions. Your input string complies with the number format for `Locale.US`.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String input = "1,514,230.15";
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
        double n = numberFormat.parse(input).doubleValue();
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1514230.15
```