# How to change all dot characters to comma for entire Android app?

Tags: java, android, number-formatting

I use a lot decimal characters with dot. but they should be written with comma.  Is there a way I can change all of them?

Comment: By the way: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5054132/589259 . OK question goes the other way, but techniques will be identical. Note that this kind of Android functionality is taken from Java, so it is not Android specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.format("%,d", number)
```

or

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(5000);
```

or

```
DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.'); 
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(formatString, otherSymbols);
currentLocale can be obtained from Locale.getDefault() i.e.:

Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
```