# DecimalFormat("0.0") returns data with a comma as separator instead of a point

Tags: java, decimalformat

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class FormatTest {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");

        System.out.println(df.format(10.4));  // prints 10,4 instead of 10.4
        System.out.println(df.format(100.5)); // prints 100,5 instead of 100.5
        System.out.println(df.format(3000.3));// prints 3000,3 instead of 3000.3
    }
}
```

The output of my code above is below with a comma as decimal separator while normally it should be with a point. I use NetBeans 12.5 with Maven.

It seems like Java uses my local decimal separator instead of point. Also, I need to force point (".") as the only separator.

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ FormatTest ---

10,4

100,5

3000,3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (and you actually need to avoid localization) actively configure the `DecimalFormat` with more detail as follows:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
        DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        decimalFormatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
        df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
        
        System.out.println(df.format(10.4));  // prints 10,4 instead of 10.4
        System.out.println(df.format(100.5)); // prints 100,5 instead of 100.5
        System.out.println(df.format(3000.3));// prints 3000,3 instead of 3000.3
    }
}
```

You can read more details in the [reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), where an important snippet can be read:

> Special Pattern Characters
>
> (...)
>
> The characters listed here are used
> in non-localized patterns. Localized patterns use the corresponding
> characters taken from this formatter's DecimalFormatSymbols object
> instead, and these characters lose their special status.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the decimal format like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054132/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-of-decimalformat-from-comma-to-dot-point)

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
```

Comment: In fact, in my code I use a solution on the same link, using .replace(',', '.') but I thought one could have something better (but equally short using DecimalFormat).